# RollOffFactor and RefDifference have no effect in Web Audio / ThreeJS (inside VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, three.js, controls, web-audio-api

I have quite some experience with JavaScript and Web Audio, but I am not able to figure out why changing the RollOffFactor and RefDifference have no effect on how fast the sounds fade away after navigating in the space and it's absolutely required in this project. I waited a long time to post this one here. Seen on Chrome, FireFox and Safari. I am working with ThreeJS and Web Audio and I am aware of the different ways these properties can be set: directly setting the Web Audio `posAudioArray[i].panner.refDistance` and `posAudioArray[i].panner.rolloffFactor`, or with the ThreeJS containers such as `posAudioArray[i].setRefDistance()` and `posAudioArray[i].setRolloffFactor()`

This is the [link](https://www.sound-office.online/listeningroom/) to the website. There are sounds playing in a 3 dimensional space and when navigating, the sounds should fade out fast so that it's possible to listen to the isolated sounds. Right now you hear all the sounds at the same time (even though the stereo panning itself works).

When logging the PannerNode Objects in the console, it is clear that the Panner values are set:

[Panner refDistance and rollOffValue values read from the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNsew.png)

[Panner distanceModel values read from the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWVKf.png)

For both values I tried values from 0.1 to 1 and I also tried the other distance models, but it doesn't have any effect at all.

This is the full Panner object:
[Screenshot of the Panner object in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c5er.png)

This is the relevant part of the code where I create the Panner Nodes, I don't set any custom volume or gain level. For legibility I removed all the occurrences of "this" from Vue options API:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
let cameraSettings = [62, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 9000];
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...cameraSettings);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
...
let listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add(listener);
var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
...


>! inside a loop

posAudioArray[i] = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listener);

      audioLoader
       .loadAsync(soundObject.content.audiofiles[0].url)
       .then((buffer) => {
          console.log(this.posAudioArray[i]);

          audioRefArray[i].add(this.posAudioArray[i]);
              
          posAudioArray[i].setDistanceModel('linear');
          posAudioArray[i].setBuffer(buffer);
          posAudioArray[i].setRefDistance(0.1);
          posAudioArray[i].setLoop(true);
          posAudioArray[i].setRolloffFactor(0.1);
          fadeInAudio(this.posAudioArray[i]);
        });
        audioRefArray[i].layers.enableAll();
        scene.add(this.audioRefArray[i]);
      }
    }
```

and the faceInAudio methods is currently nothing more than this:

```
    fadeInAudio(obj) {
      obj.play();
    },
```

I use the [CameraControls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camera-controls) library. But I can't imagine this wrapper conflicting with the RefDistance or RollOff:

```
var cameraControls = new CameraControls(
  camera, renderer.domElement
);
```

I would be so happy if anyone encountered this, I am truly breaking my head over this.

Comment: Hi! I am facing similar issues (I think) with my website. It is working perfectly well on Chrome and Firefox = all the different domes have their own sound source which you can navigate towards - BUT on Safari I hear all the dome-sounds at the same time. I have the feeling the rollofffactor works differently or is somehow ignored on Safari?! i hope anyone can shed some light on this. The website: https://yggdrasil-908ca4owk-dataexcess.vercel.app/ . btw I love your website! very cool :)